# Applying custom action on jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jquery easing effect](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and right now I have following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";
    $('#myDiv ul li.submenu a.title').click(function(e) {
       var dropDown = $(this).parent().next();
       $('.submenu_items').not(dropDown).slideUp('slow');
       dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

using this js code all list items inside unordered list at `#myDiv` are unwrapped. What I'm trying to achive is to send from my controller some string which will represent div identifier, so instead of `#myDiv` should be dynamic value sent from controller. Under that div all items should be unrapped and all other should be hidden (wrapped).

- DivOne

  - List item
  - List item two
- DivTwo
- DivThree

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Dom structure is following

```
<!-- menu one  -->
<ul>
  <li id="first_menu" class="submenu">
    <a href="#" class="title">FIRST MENU</a>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
   <ul class="nomargin"> 
     <li><a href="link1">LINK ONE</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="link2">LINK TWO</a></li>                                                                                
        </ul>
      </li> 
    </ul>    
  </ul>
<!-- / menu one -->


<!-- menu two -->
    <ul>
      <li id="second_menu" class="submenu">
        <a href="#" class="title">SECOND MENU</a>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
       <ul class="nomargin"> 
         <li><a href="link3">LINK THREE</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="link4">LINK FOUR</a></li>                                                                                
            </ul>
          </li> 
        </ul>    
      </ul>
    <!-- / menu two -->
```

I want on page load to unwrapped all list items from lets say FIRST MENU, and items from SECOND MENU to remain wrapped (this should wait onclick event, but that's not the issue right now).

Comment: In case you are trying to create your own custom animation/action effect... read this blog http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/06/22/how-to-use-custom-jquery-animation-queues/

Comment: actually I'm not, I just trying to achive unwrapped ul li items under dynamic divvalue when page loads.

Comment: There are no `DIV` tags in your sample HTML - I'm assuming that they just wrap round each of the outer `UL` tags for the menus (and there is a missing `LI` closing tag between the last two `UL` closing tags for each menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the effect you were after:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cWXm5/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";
    var submenus = $( '.submenu_items' );
    $( 'div.menu ul li.submenu' ).each( function(){
        var submenu  = $( this ),
            dropdown = submenu.next(),
            items    = submenus.not( dropdown );

        $( 'a.title', submenu ).click( function(e){
            items.slideUp( 'slow' );
            dropdown.stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault();
        } );
    });
});
```

When you click the title then the menu items in the other divs will be slid up and hidden and the current sub-menu will have its sub-menu toggled.

**Edit:**

A more efficient version of this is:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cWXm5/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";
    var current_submenu = null;
    $( 'div.menu ul li.submenu' ).each( function(){
        var dropdown = $( this ).next();
        $( 'a.title', this ).click( function(e){
            if ( current_submenu !== null && current_submenu != dropdown )
            {
                current_submenu.slideUp( 'slow' );
            }
            current_submenu = dropdown;
            dropdown.stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault();
        } );
    });
});
```

**Edit 2:**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cWXm5/12/)

```
dynamic_value_from_controller = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";

    var menus = $( 'div.menu ul li.submenu' ),
        current_submenu = null;
    menus.next().hide();
    menus.each( function(i){
        var dropdown = $( this ).next(),
            title = $( 'a.title', this );
        title.click( function(e){
            if ( current_submenu !== null && current_submenu != dropdown )
            {
                current_submenu.slideUp( 'slow' );
            }
            current_submenu = dropdown;
            dropdown.stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault();
        } );
        if ( i == dynamic_value_from_controller )
            title.click();
    });
});
```

**Edit 3**

Added a `dynamic_value_from_controller` variable into the previous edit to control which menu is initially opened.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cWXm5/14/)

Comment: @MTO thanks for your time, I edited my question with dom structure.

Comment: Updated and put together a JSFiddle.

Comment: Great, just one more thing, one page load FIRST_MENU items should be unwrapped.

Comment: unfortunately I can vote and accept only one time :) Many thanks.

Comment: How can change this example to open second_menu unwrapped instead of first_menu. I need this cause I will use dynamic value sent from controller.

Comment: the line near the bottom `if ( i == 0 )` determines which sub-menu is initially opened - just replace the `0` with the dynamic value and it should work.

Comment: I'm struggle with this, if you have time please answer with example on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327525/unwrap-list-items-in-jquery-based-on-controller-value